# Facebook - fb graph api js sdk giving wrong response for user-id

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using facebook graph api using javascript sdk. I'm fetching page feed with their likes count and user and same for comment. but after some time I'm getting wrong user_id for all the  page post like and comments.

when I'm trying to get this using facebook graph explorer it is giving me right result.
I've used app_access_token and user-access-token..
what is wrong with facebook graph api.

Comment: What do you mean with wrong user_id? Could it be that you get an app scoped user id back?

Comment: I mean first few character of user_id are same but other are different. I have cross checked this using the name variable in the response JSON. names are same but user_id are different.

Comment: Sounds like a app scoped user id to me. But you can always report it as a bug on developers.facebook.com/bugs and someone will look into it

Comment: can you explain me what is app scoped user id??

Comment: Facebooks upgrade guide explains it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Answer (score 2):

You are probably talking about "App Scoped IDs": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Apps don´t return real User IDs anymore, only IDs bound to one specific App. The Graph API Explorer should return the exact same ID for a User, as long as you select the same App before making an API call.